# sql query for getting data between 2 dates which are explicitly given

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I want to get data betwenn 2 dates and these dates are supplied by the user.

what i did is as follows

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getattndncchart
(
@date1 varchar(50),
@date2 varchar(50)
)   
AS
SELECT * FROM Tbl_Date WHERE Date BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2
```

but am not getting the result. pls help me out.

Comment: is your Date should be different type instead of `varchar(50),` ?

Comment: ***WHY oh WHY*** are you using `VARCHAR(50)` for a date?!??!?!?! **Use the most appropriate datatype** - make those parameters `DATE` or `DATETIME2(3)` or something like that!!

Comment: Also, `DATE` is a reserved keyword in SQL Server - you should *avoid* using it as the **column name** - use a more meaningful column like, like `SaleDate`, or `PurchaseDate` or whatever it really is - don't just use an extremely generic name like `Date` .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is your Date should be different type instead of `varchar(50),` ?

I am never used procedures, so maybe I am wrong. Maybe something like this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getattndncchart
@date1 date,
@date2 date 
 AS
  BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM Tbl_Date WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2
 END;
```

Also, `Date` in your `WHERE` clause needs to be surrounded by `[ ]` (since it is a reserved word).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have several errors here:

1) As Andrew points out, you can't compare dates that are not the correct type. So you should parse the     values as a date or datetime into the stored procedure from your application.

2) In order to do a comparison of dates, you must have another date type to compare it to. For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getattndncchart
(
@date1 date,
@date2 date
)   
AS
DECLARE @curdate date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

SELECT * 
FROM Tbl_Date 
WHERE @curdate BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2
```